# WebView action when view did not load (Cocoa OS X)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, alert

Hi is there a way to programaticly have a NSAlert show up when the view can not be loaded, I'm trying to make a WebView that loads a web server and when the server is not online i want a NSAlert to show up. Ive gotten this far

```
-(void)checkView{

    if(webView ???????){
    NSString *server = ipbox.stringvalue;

    [[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"The Server is offline" defaultButton:@"OK" alternateButton:@"" otherButton:@"" informativeTextWithFormat:@"The server %@ is down", server] runModal];    

    }

    else{
      nil;
    }
}
```

im not sure what to put in the "if" part of this. Ive tried webViewDid but there is no webViewDidLoad in OS X. So basically I'm looking for something like 'view failed to load', thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the delegate method:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    //NSLog(@"%@", error);
    [[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"The Server is offline" defaultButton:@"OK" alternateButton:@"" otherButton:@"" informativeTextWithFormat:@"The server %@ is down", server] runModal];    


}
```